# Is using "@" to suppress warnings/notices right?

Tags: php

I guess, the title itself explains the question....:)

Is it right to use `@` to suppress PHP warnings and notices?
For example, In:-

```
if (isset($someArray['somekey'])) {
    $myVar = $someArray['somekey'];
}
```

and in:-

```
$myVar = @$someArray['somekey'];
```

which one is right way? And why the other one is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it right to use @ to suppress PHP warnings and notices ?

### No

> which one is right way?

The first method.

> And why the other one is wrong?

Both the methods makes `$myVar` to be assigned a `NULL` , but you should not try to suppress errors/warnings.

---

**Explanation for your comment :**

Well you don't wanna know what caused your script to show some weird output when you are expecting something else?

Say if you are running this code..
`echo $source=file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");` Consider if `google.com` is down then you would get an notice on your script like ..'hostname not found` , By reading this informational message , you could very well know that your code is right but the issue is only with Google Servers.

Say if you had `echo $source=@file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");` , Nothing would be printed , However you would be expecting a HTML source.

### Are you getting the picture ?

Comment: `but you should not try to suppress errors/warnings.`, but why?

Comment: Thanks, well explained.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't write code which produces warnings, however, you should turn off warnings and notices when running in production environment.
and that is done through a global settings through [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not suppress errors with `@`.  When you're developing you'll want to be able to see errors, and in production your project should have error reporting turned off via php.ini rather than `@`.

Answer (score 0):

turn of warning and notice errors by putting

`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING))`

in top of your code in **production** level and handle errors with a custom error reporting method written by yourself.

but in development level just put `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` and read the errors, notices are not important, even in development level.

one of the advantages of preventing warning errors with `error_reporting`, is that even in the production level , if a problem occurs, you can simply debug it by changing the `error_reporting` value to `E_ALL` and  read the errors and solve it .

[here  is the manual of errro_reporting() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)